# Firebase Storage Upload Task - Security Exception on Content Resolver

Tags: android, firebase-storage

In my android app, I am trying to provide a facility for users to select photos from their Google photos album and upload to the app. The function works well when i am retrieving a `Uri` from the Google photos and displaying that image in an `imageview` using the retrieved `uri`. However, when I user the same uri to upload the image into Firebase Storage, the app crashes at the following line of code:

```
UploadTask uploadTaskPic = picReference.putFile(picUriLocal);
```

The `picUriLocal` is the Uri I receive from Google photos. Stacktrace of the error given below:

```
    12-17 11:31:41.814 18971-18971/me.buddy.buddy E/AndroidRuntime: 
        FATAL EXCEPTION: main

Process: me.buddy.buddy, PID: 18971 
java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial:  opening provider com.google.android.apps.photos.contentprovider.impl.MediaContentProvider from 
ProcessRecord{27fa910 18971:me.buddy.buddy/u0a154} (pid=18971, uid=10154) that is not exported from uid 10057                                                                                  at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1629)                                                                                  at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1582) 
atandroid.app.ActivityManagerProxy.getContentProvider(ActivityManagerNative.java:3598)
                at android.app.ActivityThread.acquireProvider(ActivityThread.java:5172)
                at android.app.ContextImpl$ApplicationContentResolver.acquireUnstableProvider(ContextImpl.java:2026)
                at android.content.ContentResolver.acquireUnstableProvider(ContentResolver.java:1481)
                at android.content.ContentResolver.openTypedAssetFileDescriptor(ContentResolver.java:1101)
                at android.content.ContentResolver.openAssetFileDescriptor(ContentResolver.java:955)                                                                                  at android.content.ContentResolver.openFileDescriptor(ContentResolver.java:808)at android.content.ContentResolver.openFileDescriptor(ContentResolver.java:762)
                at com.google.firebase.storage.UploadTask.<init>(Unknown Source)
                at com.google.firebase.storage.StorageReference.putFile(Unknown Source)
                at me.buddy.buddy.ui.UserProfile.saveAndClose(UserProfile.java:211)
                at me.buddy.buddy.ui.UserProfile.access$000(UserProfile.java:68)
                at me.buddy.buddy.ui.UserProfile$1.onClick(UserProfile.java:97)
                at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5232)
                at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21289)
                at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:168)
                at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5885)
                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:797)
                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:687)
```

In the documentation for the `UploadTask` it states that the:

uri:

```
The source of the upload. This can be a file:// scheme or any content URI. A content resolver will be used to load the data.
```

So I am not able to figure out why the Security Exception.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This security exception was happening due to a content resolver issue. `GooglePhotos` was returning a `"content://"` uri which the above code was not able to read, specifically the `UploadTask`. So I loaded the image from the googlePhotos, into an `imageview`. And I created a local `file://` uri from the bitmap of this image. And it resolved the security exception. Feel free to add comment if the answer is not clear enough.